# jQuery hover function not working on 'BxSlider' loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

Hi guys I have a slightly strange problem, and basically on this page:

http://www.carbondelight.co.uk

I have 6 images/products on an infinite loop powered by the BxSlider (http://bxslider.com/), that bit is simple.

I have then coded in jQuery a function that displays the products name when you hover over the respective product image.

The problem I'm having is that the hovering only works on each loop and does not cross over to the next loop. For example if you take a look at the page mentioned earlier you'll notice that the last image in the loop is two back seats of a red car, and if you try and hover between that image and the boat image next to it you will get no change in the product name. But if you move completley into the next loop all of the jQuery works again. And for the life of me I cannot solve this issue. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you everyone in advance.

Daniel.

The code is here.

```
    $('.newp-hover').mouseenter(function() {
    var imgValue = $(this).attr("name");
    //alert(imgValue);
    $('.newp-pre').hide();
    $('.newp-name').hide();
    $('.' + imgValue).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

and the HTML is here

```
<div id="new-p-con">
    <div class='newp-title textshadow'>NEW PRODUCTS</div><div class='newp-bt-con'><div class="newp-left-btn" id="go-prev2"></div><div class="newp-right-btn" id="go-next2"></div></div>
    <div class="newp-img-con">
                <ul id="slider5">
                        <?php

                        for ( $j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j )
                        {
                            $row = mysql_fetch_row($result3);
                            $sql4 = "SELECT smlImg FROM imageTable WHERE partID='$row[0]'";
                            $product = performQuery($sql4);
                             //displays the product images
                            echo "<li class='newp-li'><a href='prodview.php?id=$row[0]' class='newp-hover' name='$j'><img src='$image$product[0]' /></a></li>";
                        }
                        ?>
                </ul>
        <div class="newp-name-con">
        <?php
            //finds the first product name
            $showyou = performQuery($sql5);

        for ( $j = 0 ; $j < $rows5 ; ++$j )
        {
            $row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result5);
            //displays the first product name so a name shows when page is loaded
            echo "<p class='none newp-name $j'>$row2[1]</p>";
        }

        ?>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a [`live event`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of binding the `mouseenter` event directly like you are doing (so `$('.newp-hover').mouseenter(` becomes `$('.newp-hover').live('mouseenter', `)

Comment: I have not, how does this function operate differently? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: basically when you use `.mouseover()` it binds to the elements that exists when you make the call. Using `.live()` It binds to those that exists and all future ones created. I think your problem is more are added later that don't get bound when you originally bind up there.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll give it a go shortly Chad, thanks for the help.

Could you give me any more info on how my function would look using the .live function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got a feeling that the slider is creating more elements after you do the initial binding of the `mouseover` event. Since you are binding using `.mouseover()` only elements that *exist at the time you bind* will trigger the event.

If the slider is adding more after you bind a [`live` event](http://api.jquery.com/live/) will fix your issue. Instead of binding to elements existing at the time of binding, it does that *plus* all future elements matching the selector:

```
$('.newp-hover').live('mouseenter', function() {
    var imgValue = $(this).attr("name");
    //alert(imgValue);
    $('.newp-pre').hide();
    $('.newp-name').hide();
    $('.' + imgValue).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

---

**EDIT**

`.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery v1.7. Instead you should use delegate events:

```
$(documents).on('mouseenter', '.newp-hover', function() {
    var imgValue = $(this).attr("name");
    //alert(imgValue);
    $('.newp-pre').hide();
    $('.newp-name').hide();
    $('.' + imgValue).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks mate worked an absolute charm. I had no idea about this function either. I don't think I ever would have figured this out.

Thank you.